# Ubuntu 12.04 - Cannot remove fglrx

Tags: ati, radeon, fglrx

I want to use the open source Radeon driver for Ubuntu, but currently I'm using fglrx.

So, I went ahead and purged fglrx using `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*` and when I rebooted and ran `sudo lshw -c video`, I still see `driver=fglrx_pci`. I've followed the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1857059&highlight=effenberg%20ati).

I'm not sure why I can't completely purge fglrx, is anyone else experiencing this? I also checked Synaptic Package Manager and Additional Drivers and it says I'm not using fglrx at all. I'm not sure if I'm really using fglrx now.

Have anyone else encountered this? Thanks.

Comment: ehh i am not completely sure about the command u used. I always use this `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`

Comment: also tried running that, but still same result.

Comment: Did u tried via GUI: system settings> Driver

Comment: Yup, it says I don't use fglrx anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to blacklist this driver. Issue this command as root:
 `echo "blacklist fglrx_pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx_pci.conf`

Reboot.

Comment: Hmm..it says 'bash: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx_pci.conf: Permission denied', even with sudo.

Comment: Issue `sudo su` before, after that issue my command.

Comment: I've tried that, but still the same error.

Comment: I used vim instead and added the blacklist fglrx_pci line, worked great. Now using the radeon driver, thanks!