# Unable to update display driver in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, fglrx, amd-graphics

I am trying to update my driver and see this screen. It doesn't allow me to update the driver. Note the greyed out options. How can I fix this?
[image]

EDIT: [Revert to open source graphics drivers - options greyed out 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587582/revert-to-open-source-graphics-drivers-options-greyed-out-14-04)

```
$ lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks GL [FirePro V4900]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 2b06
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

but when I do

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx_pci
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fglrx_pci
```

Even tried following steps at https://askubuntu.com/a/190187/393311 but still am stuck with `fglrx_pci` and options are greyed out.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for siddjain: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Turks GL [FirePro V4900]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d3d20000-d3d3ffff ioport:7000(size=256) memory:d3d00000-d3d1ffff
```

here is contents of `/usr/share/ati`

```
$ ls /usr/share/ati
fglrx-install.log  LICENSE.TXT
```

and here is contents of log file

```
$ cat /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log 
NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve package-dependency issues.
Package dh-modaliases is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install dh-modaliases.
Package execstack is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install execstack.
Package dpkg-dev is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install dpkg-dev.
Package debhelper is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install debhelper.
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 301: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: dpkg-buildpackage: not found
[Error] Generate Package - error generating package : Ubuntu/trusty
```

contents of `/etc/X11`:

```
$ ls /etc/X11
app-defaults             fonts    xkb       Xresources  Xsession.options
cursors                  rgb.txt  Xreset    Xsession    xsm
default-display-manager  xinit    Xreset.d  Xsession.d  Xwrapper.config
```

I downloaded `amd-driver-installer-15.201.2401-x86.x86_x64.run` from AMD website and ran it (also had to install its dependencies first). Rebooted and started facing this problem: [Can't login after Nvidia driver install v 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624966/cant-login-after-nvidia-driver-install-v-14-04). Booted in recovery mode and tried various things. Finally somehow was able to login (I think I purged `fglrx`) and got to this stage:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for siddjain: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Turks GL [FirePro V4900]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d3d20000-d3d3ffff ioport:7000(size=256) memory:d3d00000-d3d1ffff
```

I am past the greyed out options but the display is all screwed up and it is using software renderer.
[image]

Took a chance and selected `fglrx-updates`. Logged out and now the display is at proper resolution. Final setup:

[image]

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for siddjain: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Turks GL [FirePro V4900]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:60 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d3d20000-d3d3ffff ioport:7000(size=256) memory:d3d00000-d3d1ffff
```

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal first.

Comment: when you install a driver manually, the install script should also contain an uninstall script. Remove the manually installed driver, reboot and your options should be clickable.

Comment: How to remove manually installed driver? I have run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Still struggling with it. No idea where to find the uninstall file of this manually installed driver.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VideoDriverHowto

Comment: Where did you get the driver that you manually installed?

Comment: These options were not greyed out originally but I was having problems with my display so I experimented with all 3 options and at some point it just changed to grey

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
 sudo apt-get install fglrx*-
```

and it might work fine this way.